# Tag wikis accepted, but excerpts rejected

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-suggestion, suggested-edits

I thought I could help by suggesting a few new tag wikis. Most were accepted, but in 3 of them, the tag wiki body was accepted but the excerpt was rejected, leaving them with no summary.

The edits are:

- https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/3925
- https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/3914
- https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/3916

I didn't see anything immediately wrong with these, with respect to http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/. Am I misunderstanding what the tag wiki excerpt is for?

Comment: I pinged the user who rejected your tag wiki excerpts in chat, and asked him to take a look at this question. It looks to me like they're all fine suggestions, so I'm not really sure personally.

Comment: that is odd, they look fine to me too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The user who rejected your suggestions [said in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1528426#1528426):

> I thought they were re-writes of previous edits. :( Sorry about that, can I do anything to fix it?

Sorry that there was a mistake, it looks like another user misunderstood the distinction between the suggested tag wiki edits and the tag wiki excerpts. This user has just hit 10k, and had probably not seen the suggested edits queue before, which is probably what led to the confusion.

If you re-suggest the edits, I will go and approve them. Thanks for helping out the site with tag wikis!

Comment: I've re-suggested them.

Comment: It looks like they've been accepted this time around. Thanks!

Comment: @Mechanical snail - yeah that was, me... Sorry about that, my "newb" hat was on that day. :)  I thought they were rewrites of the same suggestion.

Comment: It has happened again (with a different user). Evidently the UI is confusing, so I'm [proposing the review interface be changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103380/confusing-review-ui-leads-editors-to-accept-tag-wikis-while-rejecting-correspondi).